# Finding a sequence that satisfies certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose that $t > 1$ is fixed. I'm trying to find a sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ possibly dependent on $t$ that satisfies the following conditions:

1) $x_k \to 0$ as $k\to \infty$;

2) $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{\sqrt[t]{x_k}}{k} < \infty$;

3) $t^{-\tfrac{n}{2}} \leq C_t \; x_1x_2 \cdots x_n,$ for every $n \geq 1$ and some constant $C_t$.

If we put $x_k = \frac{1}{k}$, then the first two conditions are fulfilled, but I can't get the third fails since we get a factorial on the right hand side which falls off much more quickly then the power on the left hand side.

If we put $x_k = t^{-k}$, the first two conditions are again fulfilled, and in the third we get $ t^{-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$ on the right hand side. I don't see a way to find a $C_t$ such that the estimate holds.

If we put $x_k = \frac{1}{\log(1+k)}$, then the sum in $2)$ diverges.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What about $$t^{-tE[\sqrt k]}$$

Comment: $E[\sqrt{k}]$ being?

Comment: The integer part of $\sqrt k$

Comment: Interesting! However I would prefer an example without "functions" such as $E$.